# How to handle sqlalchemy ObjectDeletedError with session.merge() and table is deleted

Tags: merge, sqlalchemy

I have a table row that is created, and periodically updated, with session.merge().  If the table in the DB (sqlite) is deleted, then I get an ObjectDeletedError, but I can't find a way to gracefully handle this.

On exception, I recreate the table, but the exception still occurs.

What do I need to do to get the session to recognise the new table, create the row and continue on as before ??

Here is the code ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

##============================================================================

class Module(Base):
    """Schema for the modules table."""

    ##------------------------------------------------------------------------

    __tablename__ = "modules"

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    port = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer)

    ##------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self, id, port=None):
        self.id = id
        self.port = port

##============================================================================

class SessionMgr(object):
    """Class to manage the database session."""

    ##------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self, commitInterval=5, debug=False):
        self.commitInterval = commitInterval

        database = "merge-bug.db"
        self.engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///%s" % (database), echo=debug)

        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()

        self.create_tables()

    ##------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def create_tables(self):
        """Create database tables if they do not exist."""

        ### List of tables to check/create.
        tables = [ Module ]

        ### Create each table if it does not exist.
        for t in tables:
            tname = t.__tablename__
            if not self.engine.dialect.has_table(self.engine.connect(), tname):
                print "%s table didn't exist. Creating..." % (tname)
                t.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

    ##------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def commit(self):
        """Commit changes to the database."""
        print "Committing to db"
        try:
            self.session.commit()
        except Exception as ex:
            print "ERROR: SessionMgr.commit():", ex
            print "DEBUG: SessionMgr.commit(): Issuing a session rollback ..."
            self.session.rollback()
            ## Check that tables still exist.
            self.create_tables()
        finally:
            ## Optional -- depends on use case.
            #self.session.remove()
            pass

    ##------------------------------------------------------------------------

##============================================================================

def main():
    print "DEBUG: main():"

    import time

    sessmgr = SessionMgr(commitInterval=5, debug=False)

    ##
    ## Test adding a module and updating it using session.merge().
    ##
    if 1:
        errors = 0
        m = Module(1234, 43210)
        print "DEBUG: merge module"
        mm = sessmgr.session.merge(m)
        sessmgr.commit()
        delay = 1
        for i in range(10):
            try:
                print "DEBUG: sleeping %i second ..." % (delay)
                time.sleep(delay)
                port = mm.port + 1
                print "DEBUG: updating port field to %i ..." % (port)
                ## Exception on the following statement if table is deleted !!
                mm.port = port
                sessmgr.commit()
                print "DEBUG: updating id field ..."
                mm.id = 1234
                sessmgr.commit()
            except Exception as ex:
                print "DEBUG: caught exception", ex
                if 0:
                    print "DEBUG: Issuing a session rollback ..."
                    sessmgr.session.rollback()
                if 1:
                    print "DEBUG: Create tables ..."
                    sessmgr.create_tables()
                if 1:
                    print "DEBUG: Remerge module ..."
                    m = Module(1234, 43210)
                    mm = sessmgr.session.merge(mm)
                if 0:
                    print "DEBUG: Refresh merged module ..."
                    mm = sessmgr.session.merge(mm)
                errors += 1
                print "DEBUG: errors =", errors
                if errors > 3:
                    raise

##============================================================================

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

##============================================================================
```

Here is the output ...

```
DEBUG: main():
DEBUG: merge module
Committing to db
DEBUG: sleeping 2 second ...
DEBUG: updating port field to 43211 ...
Committing to db
DEBUG: updating id field ...
Committing to db
DEBUG: sleeping 2 second ...
DEBUG: caught exception (OperationalError) no such table: modules u'SELECT modules.id AS modules_id, modules.port AS modules_port \nFROM modules \nWHERE modules.id = ?' (1234,)
DEBUG: Create tables ...
modules table didn't exist. Creating...
Committing to db
DEBUG: Remerge module ...
DEBUG: errors = 1
DEBUG: sleeping 2 second ...
DEBUG: caught exception Instance '<Module at 0x102a586d0>' has been deleted, or its row is otherwise not present.
DEBUG: Create tables ...
Committing to db
DEBUG: Remerge module ...
DEBUG: errors = 2
DEBUG: sleeping 2 second ...
DEBUG: caught exception Instance '<Module at 0x102a586d0>' has been deleted, or its row is otherwise not present.
DEBUG: Create tables ...
Committing to db
DEBUG: Remerge module ...
DEBUG: errors = 3
DEBUG: sleeping 2 second ...
DEBUG: caught exception Instance '<Module at 0x102a586d0>' has been deleted, or its row is otherwise not present.
DEBUG: Create tables ...
Committing to db
DEBUG: Remerge module ...
DEBUG: errors = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge_bug.py", line 135, in <module>
    main()
  File "merge_bug.py", line 103, in main
    port = mm.port + 1
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 316, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 611, in get
    value = callable_(passive)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 375, in __call__
    self.manager.deferred_scalar_loader(self, toload)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 606, in load_scalar_attributes
    raise orm_exc.ObjectDeletedError(state)
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.ObjectDeletedError: Instance '<Module at 0x102a586d0>' has been deleted, or its row is otherwise not present.
```

Answer (score 0):

> What do I need to do to get the session to recognise the new table, create the row and continue on as before ??

when an error occurs with the Session you need to roll it back to cancel the current transaction:

```
session.rollback()
```

now if you are still having this issue, then it is likely that SQLite can't handle the table being dropped (I assume by a different connection?) you may need to reconnect to the database entirely - disabling connection pooling using `NullPool` will achieve this, each time the Session closes its transaction, the connection itself will be closed.

It's also not really the appropriate use of a relational database to be creating and dropping tables as the application is running.   If you need to delete all the data in a table, use "DELETE FROM table".  The table structure itself should not be changing while the application is running (especially on a fragile system like SQLite).

Comment: session.rollback() does not solve the issue.  I've now tested on mysql too and it does the same thing.  The error also occurs if I use "DELETE FROM table;".  I'm sure there must be a way to recover from this situation (even though it should never happen).

Comment: I just ran your program as is and it runs fine, so I guess something else needs to be happening at the same time?

Comment: yep.  type: 'echo -e "drop table modules;" | sqlite3' into another terminal after the program is running for a few seconds.  This will delete the table and the exceptions will come.  The same thing happens with "delete from modules".

Comment: echo -e "drop table modules;" | sqlite3 merge-bug.db